# Interference of noise when playing audio/video

Tags: laptop, audio, memory, video, sound-card

A sort of noise is getting interfered when I play audio/video in any player.

During some instance the audio or video is played very slowly for some seconds(along with noise)and plays normally after that.

I serviced my laptop(Hardware) recently,thinking that this might be the issue.But the issue still persists.

IF anybody have come across this kind of problems,drop in your suggestion  and solution

Edit 1:

I have installed windows 7 ultimate OS in my ACER laptop whose configuration is i3,4GB RAM,500GB HD and is 3 years old.

Noise in the sense is  not continous.A kind of spike(dot dot sound)

Edit 1:
I could see that during the interference CPU usage is shooting up to more than 85% which is withing 10% during normal usage.Also physical memory is always 1GB +/- 10%(ie 44%) since my RAM is 4GB.I am unable to find which process/thread is creating that scenario.Is there any other alternative?

Comment: you would need to describe better the noise you refer to, we can neither hear nor see it. Please extrapolate as much information as possible into the question. What is the OS? What is the hardware? what is the player even?  You could edit that all and more into the question.

Comment: @Psycogeek:Have a look at the Edit 1

Comment: Now I understand more, it is likely that there is a program messing up. you need to monitor your system with the resource monitor or task manager.  If you have a lot of accrued stuff in the system you no longer use, it might be time to clean that out. By cleaning up there will be less unnessisary stuff to observe.

Comment: @Psycogeek:Will running c cleaner/task cleaner sort out the issue? .Do you recommend anything else? Its because I tried with ccleaner but still the problem persists.

Comment: For cleanup I was referring specific to programs installed that are not used. Cleaning temps can reduce the quantity of things in there, which would make it easier to see anything going wrong there.  Then try to correlate the freezing and the noise with activity you can see with the task tools.  That could even include odd network or disk activity.

Comment: @Psycogeek:I could see that during the interference CPU usage is shooting up to more than 85% which is withing 10% during normal usage.Also physical memory is always 1GB +/- 10%(ie 44%) since my RAM is 4GB.I am unable to find which process/thread is creating that scenario.Is there any other alternative?

Comment: With a CPU stepping frequency system , the frequency or clock rate that the cpu runs at would also be important. 75% usage alone I do not concider normal, except when working on specific things that use a lot of cpu. But that also conciders the clock rate. The frequency is shown in the resource monitor in the CPU section.  What or why is that much cpu use already being used? what process?

Comment: Another simple layout to observe high levels of activity. using the Task Manager, in View menu Select Columns select to show  I/O read bytes, and I/O write bytes (disk) , and I/O other bytes. Processes that churn these numbers up are usually doing a lot of disk accesses.  Then in the question your going to have to put in more info like what processes are hogging your cpu (if any). We cant start chatting here, so instead it is going to take putting up much information of what your seeing.